# Is there a Spanish equivalent for '(sic)'?

Tags: ortografía

In English, when you quote text or speech that you know has nonstandard usage, such as misspellings or nonstandard grammar, it is typical to use ['(sic)'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28935/9983) to indicate that you *know* what you're quoting is wrong, but that you're doing it intentionally.

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sic):

> #### sic /sik; Eng. sɪk/
>
> ***adverb*** Latin .
>   so; thus: usually written parenthetically to denote that a word, phrase, passage, etc., that may appear strange or incorrect has been written intentionally or has been quoted verbatim: *He signed his name as e. e. cummings  (sic)*

Since this is Latin in origin, I can imagine the same would be used in Spanish, but is it?

Comment: If a Latin expression is used in English there's a 99.9% chance that it's usable in Spanish as well. Not 100% because there might be exceptions, although none that comes off the top of my head.

Comment: Exceptions can be "i.e." or "e.g.", I don't know if they are _accepted_, but they are not commonly used.

Comment: @DeStrangis Could you pinpoint those accepted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, *sic* or *(sic)* is also used in Spanish. From [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=sic):

> sic.
>   (Del lat. sic, así).
>
> 1. adv. U. en impresos y manuscritos españoles, por lo general entre paréntesis, para dar a entender que una palabra o frase empleada en ellos, y que pudiera parecer inexacta, es textual.

Comment: +1, (sic) is also used in newspapers.